# (Newbie question) Calculation DC-offset and RMS

Tags: amplitude, c++

Being a newbie on this topic I beg you to be indulgent to me
if my questions should be kind of "too" simple ;-)

For doing automatic analysis on my audio material
I started calculating the most simple values from the int16 samples:
Clipping count, DC-offset and RMS.

For manual manipulating audio files I use an older version
of Audition (v.3), ... but it returns different values
from the ones I calculate.

I tried Audacity - but it causes my soundcard's relais to
produce strange sounds when starting - so I better leave that.

Also tried sonic visualizer (with bbc analyse plugin),
but the latter crashes the app.

So my question:

1. Is there a free app for analysing audio
   (amplitude, rms, peaks, DC-offset, frequencies etc.)?

If you have a look at the audio piece.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/4bgf9yf6myxmfg3/test_mono.flac/file

Calculating DC-offset is the most trivial
(average of the samples), returned as % of 32768.
My result: 0,12. Audition: 0,059.

2. Who is right?

Clipping count

For that I use a kind of heuristics (derivation of samples),
which gives me similar results as Audition.

RMS

Audition returns different "aspects" of that.
(I don't have the English version, so I translate it myself)

Overall:

3. I calculate that as average of all samples' RMS, correct?
   (My value: -8,6 dB. Audition: -8,97 dB)

The other RMS aspects are dependent of the window size.
I do understand it as "parts" of the whole audio,
in which the RMS is calculated indepently.
Taking all parts' values you can take
the min, max and average values of them.

4. Correct?

But strange enough, Audition's help description of that
dialog advices to take a big window size for high dynamic range
audio (and vice versa).

5. I would have thought the other way round (???)

OK (using 50ms for window size).
Min (my app: -23,1 dB. Audition: -inf).
Max (my app: -4,8 dB. Audition: -4,5 dB).
Average (my app: -9.4 dB. Audition: -9,9 dB).

6. Who's wrong?

Last but not least I "invented" a criterion for dynamic range
(in sense of "loudness war", dynamic compressed audio),
and calculated the standard deviation of all the windows' RMS.
As percentage of the average RMS.
(Gives 43,4% for my sample)

7. Does this make sense, for a simple approach?

I hope my questions don't hurt too much ;-)

And maybe answered by few short hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for a free program I would use Python! See this link for further details on audio packages for Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804170/load-flac-file-in-python-same-as-scipy-or-librosa. I would have to import your file and run the same routines to decide who is right or wrong but you can do that and see directly using your own computations.